# list of dictionary iteration

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have `local.yml` file where I am passing variable as list

```yaml
  roles:
  - role: book
    vars:
      data:
        - 'std1'
        - 'std2'
```

`vars.yml` mentioned as below

```yaml
book_data:
  "std1": "std1"
  "std2": "std2"

"std1":
   - '1a'
   - '1b'
"std2":
   - '2a'
   - '2b'
```

I want to iterate data over list mentioned in `local.yml` and print value from `vars.yml`. I have written code which print only `list(std1,std2)`

```yaml
- name: set fact
  set_fact:
    standard: "{{ lookup('list', data) }}"

- name: get standard
  debug: msg="{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ standard }}"
```

Expected output would be:

list mentioned in `local.yml` would call `vars/main.yml` content and fetch content.
Example: whenever I would call `str1` it would fetch `1a` and `1b`,
`str2` it would fetch `2a` and `2b`

Below sample code is working:

```yaml
- name: get standard data
  debug:
    msg="{{ item.key }}"
  with_items: "{{ lookup('dict', book_data) }}"
```

but I want specific the iteration call from `local.yaml` to `vars/main.yml`. Dont want to use `vars/main.yml` variable directly into playbook

Comment: [edit] the question and make it [mre]. See the examples below.

Answer (score 0):

Given the variables

```yaml
  data: [x, y]
  book_data:
    x: std1
    y: std2
  std1: [1a, 1b]
  std2: [2a, 2b]
```

Iterate *data*, for example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('vars', book_data[item]) }}"
      loop: "{{ data }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg:
  - 1a
  - 1b

  msg:
  - 2a
  - 2b
```

, or create the structure

```yaml
  book_data_lists: |
    {% for i in data %}
    {{ i }}: {{ lookup('vars', book_data[i]) }}
    {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  book_data_lists: |-
    x: ['1a', '1b']
    y: ['2a', '2b']
```

Iterate the dictionary with subelements

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.key }} {{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ book_data_lists|from_yaml|dict2items }}"
        - value
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: x 1a
  msg: x 1b
  msg: y 2a
  msg: y 2b
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    data: [x, y]
    book_data:
      x: std1
      y: std2
    std1: [1a, 1b]
    std2: [2a, 2b]

    book_data_lists: |
      {% for i in data %}
      {{ i }}: {{ lookup('vars', book_data[i]) }}
      {% endfor %}
    
  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.key }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('dict', book_data) }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.key }}"
      loop: "{{ book_data|dict2items }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('vars', book_data[item]) }}"
      loop: "{{ data }}"

    - debug:
        var: book_data_lists

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.key }} {{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ book_data_lists|from_yaml|dict2items }}"
        - value
```

Comment: thank you for detail clarification, it got resolved from provided solutiton